# Does the concept of reasonable adjustment apply to other protected characteristics than disability status?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, disabilities, equality-act-2010

In England businesses are required to make reasonable adjustments in the case of mental or physical disabilities so as to create an inclusive environment of equality. But are such adjustments required for other protected characteristics to make a place of work or business adequately inclusive like providing halal or vegan food for a single individual where there is otherwise no necessity or demand for it?

Comment: How is the food being provided? An on-site cafeteria? Is this about a work event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No.

See [section 20](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/20?timeline=false) Equality Act 2010 which imposes the duty to make adjustments only in relation to a person's disability:

> (1) Where this Act imposes a duty to make reasonable adjustments on a person, this section, sections 21 and 22 and the applicable Schedule apply; and for those purposes, a person on whom the duty is imposed is referred to as A.
>
> (2)The duty comprises the following three requirements.
>
> (3) The first requirement is a requirement, where a provision, criterion or practice of A's puts **a disabled person** at a substantial disadvantage in relation to a relevant matter in comparison with persons who are not disabled, to take such steps as it is reasonable to have to take to avoid the disadvantage.
>
> (4) The second requirement is a requirement, where a physical feature puts **a disabled person** at a substantial disadvantage in relation to a relevant matter in comparison with persons who are not disabled, to take such steps as it is reasonable to have to take to avoid the disadvantage.
>
> (5) The third requirement is a requirement, where **a disabled person** would, but for the provision of an auxiliary aid, be put at a substantial disadvantage in relation to a relevant matter in comparison with persons who are not disabled, to take such steps as it is reasonable to have to take to provide the auxiliary aid.
>
> ...

For completeness, [section 6](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/6?timeline=false) defines a disabled person for the purposes of the Act:

> (1) A person (P) has a disability if—
>
> - (a) P has a physical or mental impairment, and
> - (b) the impairment has a substantial and long-term adverse effect on P's ability to carry out normal day-to-day activities
>
> (2) A reference to a disabled person is a reference to a person who has a disability.
>
> ...

Comment: It’s so strange that the three requirements are given in serial sibling paragraphs to the one that introduces them and not as sub paragraphs of it.

Comment: but what is an auxiliary aid?